# Using HTML tags with Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some code that is working but I would like to add two things to it that I don't know how to do.

It's a simple form that send data to my database (jQuery / AJAX) and then display the data on the web page.

Problem 1:
When I refresh the page, all the message are displayed on separate lines (which is what I want) but when I add new messages and click on the submit button, all the new messages get displayed on the same line.  Is there a way I could put a 
 or force the comment to be displayed on a new line ?

Problem 2:
When I refresh index.php, only 10 messages are displayed and that's good because I used a "LIMIT 0, 10" on my query.  When I type a new message and click on the button to submit to the database, the message list is "updating" by itself but ADD a new message to the list instead of replacing the 10th message by the new one.

index.php

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function sendMessage()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {comment : document.getElementById('message').value},
                dataType:"html",
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    $("#output").append(document.getElementById('message').value);
                    document.getElementById('message').value = "";  
                }
            }); 
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<form name="addComment">
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" />
    <input type="button" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn" value="Envoyer" onclick="sendMessage();" />
</form>

<div id="output">
</div>

<?php
include("class.php");

$object1 = new Shootbox();

try {
    $object1->showMessage();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception : ".$e->getMessage();
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
mysql_select_db("PFtest");

$message = $_POST['comment'];

if (strlen($message) > 0)
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('NULL', '".$_POST['comment']."', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
echo "Message enregistré !";   
}
elseif(strlen($message) < 0)
{
   echo "Nothing here";     
}

?>
```

class.php

```
<?php

    class Shootbox {
    public function showMessage() {
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root"); 
        mysql_select_db("PFtest");

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0 , 10");

        if(mysql_num_rows ($query)>0){
            while($result = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
                echo $result->message."<br />"; 
            }
        }
        else{
            throw new Exception("Aucune donnée dans la base de données");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's just a personal project that I'm working on to learn Javascript and PHP.

Comment: But _SQL injections!_

Comment: well, you best learn to prevent regardless if it is a personal project. People WILL hack you.

Comment: I know that SQL injection is possible on my project, it's not done yet and I will work on that after I can figure out how to make my code work properly

Answer (score 0):

You could simply append a line break. However, to make *better* html, add a p (paragraph) element around your new message. Its display defaults as block, so no need for new lines:

The jquery:

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function () {
  $("#output p:last-child").html($('#message').val());
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        comment: document.getElementById('message').value
    },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        $("#output").append(document.getElementById('message').value);
        document.getElementById('message').value = "";
    }
  });
});
```

The body:

```
<body>

<form name="addComment">
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" />
    <input type="button" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn" value="Envoyer" />
</form>

<div id="output">
<?php
include("class.php");

$object1 = new Shootbox();

try {
    $object1->showMessage();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception : ".$e->getMessage();
}


?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

For the second problem, the php should change slightly:

```
    if(mysql_num_rows ($query)>0){
        while($result = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
          echo "<p>" . $result->message."</p>"; 
          }
        }
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you ! I knew it was something like that but I just did not knew what the good "syntaxe" was.

Comment: You welcome. But actually, I'm gonna make it more "jquery" (shorter).

Comment: Oh wait, I think it solves both problems at once, doesn't it? I'm not 100% sure I understood the second one.

Comment: No, I tried with the <p> tag.  Now when I submit a new message it's on a new line but I still get more than 10 messages displayed.  + now the new messages are displayed in <p> and the 10 first message from the DB are not in <p>

Comment: Oh you want to DELETE the last message... okay, I didn't get that properly. One sec

Comment: Okay, now it should be solved. It replaces the text inside the last `<p>` inside of `<div class = "output">` for the new message.

Comment: Yes I need to delete the last message of the 10 messages that are displayed so that I always have only 10 message displayed.

Comment: Now, the message is sent to my database but it doesnt show up in the messages list. I need to refresh the page to see it..

Comment: Sorry, it was a small mistake, now that the messages are inside `<div id = "output">` it should work.

Comment: Still not working, I still have to refresh the page to see the new messages

Comment: I don't know why but it looks like the messages are not showing up in <p> even on a page refresh.  There is no padding/margin

Comment: [**It's working for me here**](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/22nNC/1/). You might want to trigger them as two separated forms? Can you check that your actual rendered html is equivalent to the one in the jsfiddle I showed? **Note: modified the code**

Comment: I might not have explained very well what I need to do..  Basically, it work like the Youtube comments.  You can see a certain amount of comments, let's say 10, and when you add your new comment, it shows up in the comments list as the newest comment (first one) and the oldest one disappear.  (On youtube you can click to "show more comments" but I don't need that option. I just need to always see a maximum of 10 messages)

Answer (score 0):

Just some speculation on what the issue might be for each of your problems.

**Problem 1** - The reason the messages are shown on separate lines only on refresh is because you're adding the break tag on the server side in your showMessage function on page load only.

You're missing the break tag in your JS for when you add a new message on submit.
So for your JS which is what you use when adding a new message after the AJAX call put the break tag on the end.

```
$("#output").append(document.getElementById('message').value + '<br>');
```

**Problem 2** - It's not replacing the 10th message on submit because you're appending to the output. So you need to remove the oldest message after appending.

Comment: Sorry if it was not very clear, english is not my primary language. Yes I need to delete the oldest message of the 10 messages that are displayed.

Comment: No you're fine. I understood after reading your discussion with Francisco Presencia :)